# Customize the collapsible column feature in Vaadin table

Tags: customization, vaadin

I have a question and wanted to see if anyone else is familiar with it.

I have a table with a quite big volume of columns and using the Vaadin collapsible feature seems like a good idea. However, I'm not totally satisfied with its standard behaviour and layout. First and foremost I would like to have a tool tip that occurs when the user moves the pointer over the feature button describing that it provides the possibility of collapsing and expanding columns. And I would also like the generic menu for choosing columns to collapse to stay up when a column has been chosen for collapse, and disappear when the user clicks outside the menu.

So... my question really is if anyone knows where I can get a hold of this feature and possibly overwrite it with my own version..? Any help would be greatly appreciated!

/Max

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't recall such features. I have both good and bad news. The good news is that you should be able to implement these features yourself by creating your own widget (see book of Vaadin for details on creating widgets). The features doesn't sound as too big changes, the code you are looking for exists in VScrollTable.

Now the bad news. VScrollTable is one of the most complex classes in core Vaadin. Even worse news, the class isn't designed to be extended/modified outside of the core framework. This means that the class contains lots and lots of private variables and methods - this can make extending the VScrollTable next to impossible. Even small and simple changes might be tedious to do. In the worst case, you'll have to copy & paste the entire class (and maybe even some other classes too) to your own widget implementation for you to be able to make the desired changes.

Comment: Really..? damn.. it sounds like that could be taking a bit more than I can chew.. hmmm.. I guess the feature in its current state will have to do. I don't have time to put all the focus required into that small part, not now at least. I'll look back at this again when I have more time though! Thank you for a very informative answer! =)